# How do I call another AWS function within the same handler.js file? And attach query string parameters?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I am using AWS Lambda and I have 2 functions within my handler.js file. I want to call the one function (getClient) within the other function. The problem I am having is that the first function (getClient) needs query string parameters and I don't know how to attach that when calling the function.

I have tried changing the event object that is sent to the function and adding the query string parameter as a json but that doesn't work.

```
    let json = JSON.parse(event.body);
    event = {
        emailAddress: json.clientEmailAddress
    }       
    var client = this.getClient(event);
    console.log(client)
```

I get the error that queryStringParameter is undefined.

errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'queryStringParameters' of undefined",

Comment: Your error message mentions `queryStringParameters` but it does not appear in the code snipet.  This means the error happens in a part of the code that you did not share here, can you add the relevant snippet ?

Comment: Also can you clarify "another AWS function" ?  Do you mean a AWS Lambda function ?  Also what do you mean by "attach querystring", maybe you meant "pass querystring as parameter" ?  Thank you for clarifying, it will help the community to answer your question.

Comment: @SébastienStormacq yes I am referring to another AWS Lambda function and I am trying to pass query string parameters. Does that help at all?

Answer (score 0):

To invoke an AWS Lambda function from another function, I would suggest to use the AWS SDK and use the `invoke` API call.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property

`Invoke` is taking an `PayLoad` parameter that can contain any object.

For example :

```js
try {
    const lambdaParams = {
       FunctionName: 'my-lambda',
       // RequestResponse is important here. Without it we won't get the result Payload
       InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
       LogType: 'Tail', // other option is 'None'
       Payload: queryStringParameters
   };

   const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({region: 'eu-west-1', apiVersion: '2015-03-31'});
   const const lambdaResult = await lambda.invoke(JSON.stringify(lambdaParams.Payload)).promise();
   logger.debug(`Lambda returned : ${lambdaResult.Payload}`);
   const resultObject = JSON.parse(lambdaResult.Payload)   

} catch (e) {
   console.error(e);
}
```